# Exporting a patch from HgWorkbench / Mercurial does not include files that were added in that commit

Tags: mercurial, export, patch, tortoisehg

When trying to export a patch for a commit, the resulting patch file doesn't include empty files that were added in the commit.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new folder and initialize it as an Hg repository.
2. Add some zero-byte file to that folder, and create an initial commit for that file.
3. Create a second zero-byte file, and create a second commit for that file.
4. In Hg Workbench, right-click on either of those commits, and choose Export >> Export Patch.
5. Open the resultant patch file in Notepad / any text viewer.
6. Observe that the patch file does not contain any information about the new files that were added.

It seems like the newly added files should be included.  If I exported that patch and someone else applied it, they wouldn't really be getting the full changeset, since the new files aren't included.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or why it behaves this way?  This is not the behavior I expected.

I'm using TortoiseHg 2.7.1, which includes Mercurial 2.5.2.

Comment: I just tried this with TortoiseHg 2.7.1 and I can see the expected diff lines in the exported patch for the new file that comprises the changeset.

Comment: I tried it with TortoiseHg 2.4.1 and hg 2.2.2 and had the new file name and its contents in the exported patch.

Comment: Hm, any guesses why I'm seeing different behavior?

Comment: I was able to get an answer in irc.freenode.net #mercurial.  It looks like this is a bug.  When committing a 0-byte file, and then generating a patch for that commit, the 0-byte files that were added do not show up in the patch file.  This has been filed as a bug here:  http://bz.selenic.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3917

Comment: @KenMason then you should add an answer yourself and accept it or delete this question.

Comment: Great that you reported the bug to the Mercurial bugtracker, thanks! That is really the correct place to go when you find bugs in Mercurial — the Mercurial developers wont generally find things you post on SO.